# Openfigi php request -> Request body must be a JSON array

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use the openfigi api with php. I keep getting this error message: "Request body must be a JSON array.". Any ideas on how to solve this? I have tried several solutions.

```
$curlUrl = 'https://api.openfigi.com/v2/mapping';

    $data = array('idType' => 'ID_WERTPAPIER', 'idValue' => '851399', 'exchCode' => 'US');   
    $j = json_encode($data);


    //$apiToken = 'X-OPENFIGI-APIKEY: xxx';

    $httpHeadersArray = Array();
    
    $httpHeadersArray[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    //$httpHeadersArray[] = $apiToken;


    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $j);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeadersArray);


    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($res);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, but solved it.

This is my working code:

```
// The url you wish to send the POST request to
$url = 'https://api.openfigi.com/v2/mapping/';

// Create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);

// The data to send to the API
$postData = array(
    array(
        "idType" => "ID_ISIN",
        "idValue" => "US4592001014"
    )
);

// Setup cURL
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));


print_r(json_encode($postData));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
die(curl_error($ch));
}

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

// Print the date from the response
print_r($responseData);
```